react nativ expo-router data with <Link>
I want to use a data from a previous screen using expo router and  .
Here is what I try:
index.js screen:
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';

export default function Page() {

    const nbData=10;
  return ( 
    <View>
      <Link href={{pathname: "./page2", params: { data: nbData }}}>p2</Link>
    </View>
  );
}

In the page2.js screen I want to use nbData. How to do it ?
I'd like to print nbData (10) in page2.js screen:
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';

export default function Page() {

  
  return ( 
      <View>

<Text> {nbData /*from index.js*/} </Text>
    </View>
  );
}


